# every item load with diffrent fancy border

Tags: php, css

hi guys i am trying to do this like i have 5 frames (fancy border) and i have items list. when items load every item load different frame. when 5 frame done then 6th frame repeat frames list. below my script

```
<?php
$allgfts=mysql_query("select id,image_url from {$statement} order by id limit {$startpoint}, {$limit}");
while($gfts=mysql_fetch_array($allgfts))
{
    $id=$gfts['id'];
    $image=$gfts['image_url'];
?>
    <div id="pic-1">
        <div class="thumbnail-item">
            <?php echo '<a href="g_detail.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="images/'.$image.'" alt="" width="161" height="161" class="thumbnail g-size" /></a>'; ?>
            <span><?php echo '<a href="g_detail.php?id='.$id.'">Readmore</a>';?></span>
            <?php echo '<a class="gtbtn" href="g_buy.php?id='.$id.'">Get This</a>';?>

        </div>     
    </div>  
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use the remainder operator("%").  I don't know what your table structure looks like, but I am going to assume your product ID loads in sequential order, starting with 1.

In your WHILE loop, use the following:

```
$remainder = $id % 5;
if($remainder == 1){
    //load my DIV with frame 1
}
else($remainder == 2){
    //load my DIV with frame 2
}
......
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to echo a list of images, with that list wrapping to a new line every fifth item.

Given an array of results from a table (consider using PDO, by the way), I would do the following:

```
//$arr being the array
$x=1; //start counter
$list = '<ul>'; //using a list, because that's what it is
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
    $list.='<li class="thumbnail-item">';
        $thumb ='<a href="g_detail.php?id='.$arr[$i][id].'">';
        $thumb.='<img src="images/'.$arr[$i][image_url].'" alt="" class="thumbnail g-size" /></a>';
        $thumb.='<span><a href="g_detail.php?id='.$arr[$i][id].'>Readmore</a></span>';
        $thumb.='<a class="gtbtn" href="g_buy.php?id='.$arr[$i][id].'">Get This</a>';
    $list.=$thumb;
    $list.='</li>';

if($x%5 == 0)||($x==count($arr)) {
    $list.='</ul>';
    if($x<count($arr)) {
        $list.='<ul>';
    }
    }
    $x++;
}
echo $list;
```

This is untested, but broadly speaking should work.